# Is there a way to make a class return an instance of its subclass with a different number of arguments in __new__?

Tags: python, class, parameters, instance

I'm trying to create a class that will return an instance of its own subclass, but I'm having trouble because the subclass has a different number of parameters than the class:

---

```py
class Number:
    def __new__(cls, number):
        if cls is Number and number == 0:
            return Zero()
        return object.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

class Zero(Number):
    def __new__(cls):
        return super().__new__(cls, 0)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(0)
        self.number = 0

Zero()  # Ok
Number(0)  # TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I know exactly why this happens, and I can easily fix it by adding a default parameter in `Zero`:

```py
class Zero(Number):
    def __new__(cls, number=0):
        return super().__new__(cls, 0)

    def __init__(self, number=0):
        super().__init__(0)
        self.number = 0
```

But, I don't like it, is there any way to fix it without adding a default parameter in `Zero`?

Comment: What are these classes supposed to do? Mutable numbers doesn't make much sense to me. Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: I fixed the title based on the problem that you actually describe in the question. `__init__` doesn't "return an instance" of anything; it is expected to return `None` implicitly, and it modifies the state of an instance that already exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like making the constructor of the subclass accept an additional parameter, you can make the parameter for the constructor of the base class optional instead:

```
class Number:
    def __new__(cls, number=0):
        if number == 0:
            cls = Zero
        return object.__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, number=0):
        self.number = number

class Zero(Number):
    def __new__(cls):
        return super().__new__(cls, 0)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/hAxtWp

If `Zero` is meant to produce a singleton, you can also consider making `Zero` an instance of `Number` instead:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, number=0):
        self.number = number

Zero = Number()
```

Answer (score 0):

> But, I don't like it, is there any way to fix it without adding a default parameter in Zero?

I think the simplest way to handle the situation is to make the subclass `Zero()` handle the same number of parameters as the base class (`Number()`).

`Number()` should also check that the argument is an instance of `int()`.

```py
class Number:
    def __init__(self, number=None):
        if isinstance(number, int):
            self.number = number
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"number must be an integer, but received {number}")

class Zero(Number):
    def __init__(self, number=0):
        super().__init__()
```